# How do I get these panels to show in a scrollable table format?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

So I am trying to reproduce this styling:

[image]

This sort of table above is being pulled in dynamically via Redux:

```
class LocationList extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchLocations();
  }

  renderLocation() {
    return this.props.locations.map(location => {
      return (
        <div className="" key={location.id}>
          <div className="location">
            <h1>
              {location.name}
              {location.airport_code}
            </h1>
            <div className="location-secondary-info">
              <span>
                <MaterialIcon icon="airplanemode_active" />
                {location.description}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="locations-container">{this.renderLocation()}</div>;
  }
}
```

However, I am having trouble getting the styling just right. So what you see above is scrollable in a vertical fashion.

I was having trouble doing it right inside my JSX, so I decided to use Codepen.io.

I can't seem to get that table format and so instead it just scrolls horizontally like one big row.

[image]

```css
.locations-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 24px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.locations-container div {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 1152px;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.location {
  border-left: 2px solid #49aaca;
  padding: 14px;
  margin: 12px 0;
  flex: 1 1;
  min-width: 275px;
  max-width: 355px;
}

.location h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #454545;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.location span {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #a3a3a3;
}

.location:hover {
  background-color: #49aaca;
}

.location:hover h1 {
  color: #fff;
}

.location:hover span {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="locations-container">
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I have reproduced it in pure HTML and CSS. Obviously, I don't know enough of Flex to figure out this last piece of design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `flex-wrap: wrap` on the container(`.locations-container`). Because it overrides the default value, which is [`nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap#Syntax). If you set `overflow-y: scroll`, you need to define the height. Example: `height:200px;`

Also to make it fix to only 3 items you can replace `flex: 1 0 1152px;` which I'm not sure why you use 1152px, but % should be preferable: `flex: 1 0 30%;`

With `flex-grow: 1` defined in the `flex` shorthand, there's no need for `flex-basis` to be 33%, which would actually result in less item per row due to the margin and padding.

Since `flex-grow` will consume free space on the row, `flex-basis` only needs to be large enough to enforce a wrap. In this case, with `flex-basis: 30%`, there's plenty of space for the margins, but never enough space for unwanted item. Note that because you have `min-width` it wouldn't be 3 items per row if it lack the space needed.

You can use [`media query`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for responsive issue. Which in example I use `width:952px;`

```css
.locations-container {
  display: flex;
  /*justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 24px;*/
  overflow-y: scroll; /*if you set overflow-y: scroll, you need to define the height.example:*/
  height:200px;
  width: 952px; /*demo purpose since you had min-width*/
  flex-wrap: wrap; /*flex-wrap: wrap on the container. Is necessary, because it overrides the default value, which is nowrap*/
}

@media (min-width: 952px){
  .locations-container{
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.locations-container div {
  display: flex;
  /*flex: 1 0 1152px;*//*I'm not sure why you use 1152px, but % should be preferable*/
  flex: 1 0 30%;
  /*flex-flow: wrap;*//*doesn't seem to do anything*/
}

.location {
  border-left: 2px solid #49aaca;
  padding: 14px;
  margin: 12px 0;
  flex: 1 1;
  min-width: 275px;
  max-width: 355px;
}

.location h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #454545;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.location span {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #a3a3a3;
}

.location:hover {
  background-color: #49aaca;
}

.location:hover h1 {
  color: #fff;
}

.location:hover span {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="locations-container">
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>FlexBox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>this is the span element</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to make it fix to 3 items.